# Flutter: constructor page called several time when a widget state change

Tags: dart, flutter

I don't understand why my class constructor is called several time when my page is refreshed
or widget value change...?
example: I send some data to a page in parameter to fill some `TextFormField` and use this textField data.

### Code sample

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AddProductPage extends StatelessWidget {
  static String tag = 'add-product-page';
  final TextEditingController _titleController = new TextEditingController();
  String text;


  AddProductPage({Key key, @required this.text}) : super(key: key) {
    _titleController.text = this.text;
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,

      controller: _titleController,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'Product Name',

        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
        //border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0)),
      ),
    );

    final addproductButton = Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
      child: RaisedButton( 
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
        ),
        onPressed: (){
          this.text =_titleController.text;
          //XXX
          //Do some stuff with this.text
        },
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
        color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        child: Text('Add Product', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
      ),
    );

    final body = Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(28.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
          Colors.white10,
          Colors.orange[200],
        ]),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[title, addproductButton],
      ),
    );

    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      body: body,
    );
  }
}
```

So in this issue If I modify my `TextFormField` to update the data,
Value of `text` is always the same as the value given in the constructor when I press on my button to get the last text of my `TextFormField`. Because the constructor is called several time when I edit my `TextFormField`.

`flutter doctor -v`

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.2.1, on Mac OS X 10.14.3 18D109, locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 1.2.1 at /Users/pierre-emmanueljacquier/flutter
    • Framework revision 8661d8aecd (3 weeks ago), 2019-02-14 19:19:53 -0800
    • Engine revision 3757390fa4
    • Dart version 2.1.2 (build 2.1.2-dev.0.0 0a7dcf17eb)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/pierre-emmanueljacquier/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses

[!] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 10.1, Build version 10B61
    ✗ ios-deploy not installed. To install:
        brew install ios-deploy
    • CocoaPods version 1.6.1

[!] Android Studio (version 3.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.31.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 2.24.0
```

Thanks

Comment: When I call `print(this.text);` after you set it in the RaisedButton `onPressed` method, it prints the text the user provided as expected. Could you elaborate on the problem?

Comment: How do you know the text hasn't changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you find if your text is not changed. Two things to be noted.

- `AddProductPage` should be a Stateful Widget to render you changed text.
- Always dispose your controller.

### Reference

Use these as your references when you're working with `TextEditingController`.
[Cookbook1](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/retrieve-input)
[Cookbook 2](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes) 
[TextEditingController](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html) Class

Comment: Thanks a lot! Set `AddProductPage` to Stateful Widget resolve this issue

Comment: @marc Please upvote/accept the answer if you found it useful. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers